Moving corner points of a rectangle in Python: is there a more elegant/compact solution?
I need to move the corner points of a rectangle by a given amount. I'm given an list of 4 3D points, each of which is a list of coordinates ([x,y,z]).
I have this, and it works OK, but feels awkward (pts is the given point list, and top, bot, and side are the given amounts to move the points):
# Get top and bottom points
upDownPts = sorted(pts, key=lambda k: [k[2]])
topPts = upDownPts[-2:]
botPts = upDownPts[0:2]

# adjust their Z coords
topPts[0][2] = topPts[0][2] - top
topPts[1][2] = topPts[1][2] - top
botPts[0][2] = botPts[0][2] + bot
botPts[1][2] = botPts[1][2] + bot

# Get left and right points
leftRightPts = sorted(pts, key=lambda k: [k[1]])
leftPts = leftRightPts[0:2]
rightPts = leftRightPts[-2:]

# adjust their Y coords
leftPts[0][1] = leftPts[0][1] + side
leftPts[1][1] = leftPts[1][1] + side
rightPts[0][1] = rightPts[0][1] - side
rightPts[1][1] = rightPts[1][1] - side

movedPts = pts

In particular, the additions and subtractions seem like they should be list comprehensions or somethng, but I couldn't make the syntax work so resorted to brute force.
Any suggestions welcome!

You could use topPts[0][2] -= top and similarly for the others.  List comprehensions are really for creating new lists, not updating existing ones.

I take it the rectangle is in an x=k plane?  since you're treating (y,z) as its 2D coordinates...

Please provide a [MRE]. We can't run your code as-is. And it would make your data clearer to actually see some.

Sorry, yes, I forgot to specify the rectangle is planar with all x coords the same. Also sorry for not making a minimal reproducible example, I thought it was simple enough for inspection. I think I have what I need now so won't go back and change things. Thanks all!

You could do something like this:
# adjust their Z coords
for point in topPts:
    point[2] -= top
for point in botPts:
    point[2] += bot


I like this for compactness, thanks! Though I might keep the explicit additions instead of += and -=

One solution here would be an object oriented approach.
class rectangle3D:
    def __init__(self, top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right):
        # Could add in some verification that the shape is indeed a rectangle here as well
        self.corners = (top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right)

    def move(self, x, y, z):
        for each in self.corners:
            each[0] += x
            each[1] += y
            each[2] += z


# test
R = rectangle3D([0,1,0], [1,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,1,0])
print(f"Initial: {R.corners}")
R.move (2, 2, -2)
print(f"After move: {R.corners}")

Produces:
Initial: ([0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])
After move: ([2, 3, -2], [3, 3, -2], [2, 2, -2], [2, 3, -2])


You can use the augmented += and -= operators there in order to shorten each   line -
But besides that, since the coordinates are being operated upon by a numeric indexes rather than by an attribute, I guess having all the explicit lines as they are in this snipped are more readable, than, say, iterating on the coordinate-index, and then on the operation signal - and even then, you'd probably be better using statement based for loops with an explicit block, as compreehnsions are not friendly to assignment of new values)
It will be easy to throw in some code-snippets with examples if you change your question to include the input data (i.e. a sample  pts object)
